# 1064 error python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database of names and prices that gets updated daily when I run it through a batch of code and update a second database all of the names until it gets to 'aapl' at which point it throws a 1064 error which looks like this

```
        -----------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testrun.PY", line 45, in <module>
    t.Push.find_all(conn, cursor)
  File "c:\tradetools.py", line 198, in find_all
    Push.find_streak(conn, cursor, name)
  File "c:\tradetools.py", line 189, in find_strea
k
    .format(c, name))
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\connections.py", line 837, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\connections.py", line 1021, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\connections.py", line 1304, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\connections.py", line 983, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\connections.py", line 395, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\p
ymysql\err.py", line 102, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "42000You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right sy
ntax to use near 'AAPL''' at line 1")

c:\>
```

The code that its running through looks like this, why does the update add more commas to the name appl?

```
def find_streak(conn, cursor, name):
    print(name)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `trade_data`.`import_data`"
                   " WHERE name =%s;", name)
    logs = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO `trade_data`.`analysis`(`name`) "
               "VALUES (%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
               "ndays=0;", name)
    conn.commit()
    logs = [list(x) for x in logs]
    logs.sort()
    ....
    cursor.execute ("UPDATE `trade_data`.`analysis` "
         "SET `ndays` = {0} WHERE name='{1}'"
         .format(c, name))
    conn.commit()
```

its pulling from a table that looks like this

```
    date|name|price|
```

and entering into a table that is

```
    date|name|result
```

Comment: are you sure about the backticks? shouldn't they be mere simple quotes?

Comment: @alexce I meant  a strait `UPDATE` in your deleted answer for the first query of his. I was even seeing the lower query. Regardless, it would seem that single quotes need to surround the `name` in both queries. But the error code looks like extra single quotes at the end. A table schema would be nice in the question as usual

Comment: Does `name` already contain single-quotes?

Comment: the name in question does have single quotes and none of the rest do but if i drop that name and rerun it it will generate a name with single quotes

Comment: tables added to the op